# Getting a widget by string

Tags: c++, qt, variables, qt5, qstring

In a for loop, I can construct a string.

```
foreach (...) {
  QString str = "pushButton" + QString::number(count);
  // this gives pushButton1

  // Now I want to get the button widget that has this string as it's variable name 
  // and modify it in some way, e.g. change it's button caption

  str->setText("New Title");

  count ++;
}
```

Is this possible? if so, then how

edited: here's how i created the buttons

```
for (int i=0; i<total; i++) {
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton();
    btn->setObjectName("pushButton" + QString::number(i));
    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(btn);
}
```

Comment: How did you create the buttons?

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc. I created it programatically in a loop and have their names assigned with the loop variable.

Comment: Have you passed a parent to the buttons?

Comment: i added them to a layout. does that automatically assign them a parent?

Comment: You can show you have created it to understand you better and give you an appropriate solution.

Comment: Ok I added the code where i created the buttons. it is in MainWindow constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the button through the `parent` and `objectName`, in your case the parent is this, so you should use the following:

```
QWidget* p =  ui->horizontalLayout->parentWidget();

for(int count=0; count<total; count++){
    const QString str = "pushButton" + QString::number(count);
    QPushButton* btn = p->findChild<QPushButton *>(str);
    btn->setText("someText");
}
```